# Limits in two variables. Basic property

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I do not remember (1) the name for the following property and (2) the conditions that $f$ must meet in order to apply it, apart from being continuous and supposing that the left-hand-side limit exists:

$$\lim \limits_{(x,y) \rightarrow +\infty}{f(x,y)}= \lim \limits_{y \rightarrow +\infty}{\left(\lim \limits_{x \rightarrow +\infty}{f(x,y)}\right)} \,\text{.}$$

Could you help me?

Comment: Thank you for editing the labels, @Git Gud. By the way, do you know the answer??

Comment: No, I'm curious.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible I'm misunderstanding the notation, but I think this is always true as long as the left-hand limit exists.

If the left hand limit exists and equals $L$, then for any neighborhood $U$ of $L$, there's a disc $D$ outside of which $f(x, y)$ is in that neighborhood. But then, for any fixed $y$, just let $x$ be large enough to be outside $D$, and $f(x, y)$ will be be inside $U$. Thus for any $y$, $\lim _{x\to \infty}f(x, y)=L$. So the right hand side is $L$ as well.

Comment: Thank you, @Jack M, but I am also interested in knowing the name for that property (I mean, something like 'the chain rule' when speaking about derivatives and so on).

Comment: @Vicent Not every property has a name. Do you have a reason to think it has one?

Comment: Well... @Jack M, I think I remember it had one particular name from my University years.